# Get an accelerometer's device id(or monitor an accelerometer in the backbround) on WinRT

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, accelerometer, background-process

I am looking into the method of monitoring accelerometer in the background.

We can get the sample for Windows Phone which implements it at [MSDN](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Background-sensors-eb7bb176).

According to the sample code, it requires the id of an accelerometer. However, there is no property which gets the device ID for WinRT.

```
var rs = await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();
if (rs != BackgroundAccessStatus.AllowedMayUseActiveRealTimeConnectivity
|| rs != BackgroundAccessStatus.AllowedWithAlwaysOnRealTimeConnectivity) return;

var btb = new BackgroundTaskBuilder() {
    Name = TaskName,
    TaskEntryPoint = TaskEntryPoint
};
btb.SetTrigger(trigger);
taskregist = btb.Register();
taskregist.Completed += new BackgroundTaskCompletedEventHandler(OnBackgroundTaskCompleted);

try {
    var dres = await trigger.RequestAsync();    // Requires the accelerometer's device-id
    switch (dres) {
    case DeviceTriggerResult.Allowed:
        break;
    case DeviceTriggerResult.LowBattery:
        break;
    case DeviceTriggerResult.DeniedBySystem:
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
} catch (InvalidOperationException) {
}
```

Can I observe an accelerometer's state in the background on WinRT devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn630194.aspx),  `DeviceUseTrigger` background task can access the sensors API only from within a Windows Runtime phone app, other winrt devices aren't supported

> **Sensors support in Windows Phone Store apps** When running on a phone, a DeviceUseTrigger background task can access the sensors API only from within a Windows Runtime app. Using a DeviceUseTrigger background task to access the sensors API from within a Windows Phone Silverlight app is not supported.

here the list of what is supported 
[image]

**And** finally here a basic example of consuming the accelerometer's data by handling the `ReadingChanged` event

```
public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.InitializeAccelerometer();
    }
    private Accelerometer _accelerometer;
    private void InitializeAccelerometer()
    {

        this._accelerometer = Accelerometer.GetDefault();
        if (_accelerometer == null)
        {
            AccelerometerTextBlock.Text = "No accelerometer found.";
            return;
        }

        uint minReportInterval = _accelerometer.MinimumReportInterval;
        var desiredReportInterval = minReportInterval > 16 ? minReportInterval : 16;
        this._accelerometer.ReportInterval = desiredReportInterval;
        this._accelerometer.ReadingChanged += Accelerometer_ReadingChanged;
    }
    private async void Accelerometer_ReadingChanged(Accelerometer sender, AccelerometerReadingChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Reading != null)
        {
            await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                AccelerometerTextBlock.Text = String.Format(
                    "X: {0,5:0.00} - Y: {1,5:0.00} - Z: {2,5:0.00} - Timestamp: {3}",
                    args.Reading.AccelerationX,
                    args.Reading.AccelerationY,
                    args.Reading.AccelerationZ,
                    args.Reading.Timestamp);
            });
        }
    }
```